# How do I force data.table to interpret a name in i as a vector in the calling environment?

Tags: r, data.table

In the R code below, how do I get the last line to use the vector `match` rather than the column in `dt` called `match`?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(cust_id = 1:4, match = NA)
match <- c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA)
dt[is.na(match)]
```

I know I can just change the name of the vector to something that is not a column in `dt`, but the data.table is going to be passed in from a function and I can't guarantee what column names it will include.

I also know I could add the `match` vector as a column to `dt` with a different name, but I don't want to have to modify `dt`.

Comment: Maybe `dt[is.na(get("match", pos=1))]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dt <- data.table(cust_id = 1:4, match = NA, 
                 is_na_match = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
match <- c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA)

dt[is_na_match]

# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, is_na_match) : 
#   is_na_match is not found in calling scope but it is a column of type logical. 
#   If you wish to select rows where that column is TRUE, either wrap the symbol 
#   with '()' or use ==TRUE to be clearest to readers of your code.
```

*(Note: this errors even though a dummy column `is_na_match` exists in this modified example of `dt`).*

Doing as suggested in the error message:

```
dt[(is_na_match)]

#    cust_id match is_na_match
# 1:       1    NA        TRUE
# 2:       3    NA        TRUE
```

While:

```
is_na_match <- is.na(match)
dt[is_na_match]

#    cust_id match is_na_match
# 1:       3    NA        TRUE
# 2:       4    NA       FALSE
```

---

From `help("data.table")`:

> *Advanced:* When `i` is a single variable name, it is not considered an
>   expression of column names and is instead evaluated in calling scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
dt[eval(is.na(match))]
```